# Does Biblical Hebrew have a plural of majesty?

Tags: hebrew, plurality

Does Biblical Hebrew have a plural of majesty?

I'm aware there's the word Elohim which can mean God or gods.

But I don't think that's good evidence of plural of majesty because for example, you have a word like Yerushalayim which means Jerusalem, is singular, but it has a dual ending as if there are two.  Or Mayim which has dual ending though refers to water.   So maybe Elohim is just a word with a plural ending.

I heard some argument from a Dr. Walter Martin ,  that Biblical Hebrew can't have a plural of majesty, because not ANE/Ancient Near East languages did. And the term came into existence in the 13th century CE, when kings linked themselves to God and said "you may come into our presence", "you may leave us". So it'd be projecting a later term and projecting it back.

Comment: It's important to remember Walter Martin was a preacher who bought a degree, not a philologist, linguist, or historian.

Comment: Obviously Hebrew had the majestic plural. See the majestic plural "lord" in Gen 24:9 and 42:30 and the majestic plural "elohim" in Exo 7:1 and Jdg 11:24.

Comment: Genesis 11:7, הָ֚בָה נֵֽרְדָ֔ה וְנָֽבְלָ֥ה שָׁ֖ם שְׂפָתָ֑ם אֲשֶׁר֙ לֹ֣א יִשְׁמְע֔וּ אִ֖ישׁ שְׂפַ֥ת רֵעֵֽהוּ: "Come, let **us** descend and confuse their speech"

Comment: See [pluralis majestatis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we), [pluralis excellentiae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralis_excellentiae), [intensive and abstract plurals](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/313773225).

Comment: Rabbi Saadia Gaon, who arguably invented Hebrew grammar, claims in his work האמונות והדעות (pp. 93-94 in the Kapach edition) that Hebrew does have a concept of "royal we."

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton for what. nouns? pronouns? examples? A royal we would be a pronoun. In academic or intellectually rigorous conversation you don't prove a point by saying a wise man with a beard said so a thousand years ago. Also you don't invent biblical hebrew grammar.. He may have been one of the first to theorize about it. Do you have examples of this "royal we" in biblical hebrew, that you suggest exists? I can think of "naaseh" "let us make.." though interesting it's translated wtih "us", not we. THough many(rabbis funnily enough), interpert that as plural for God and angels.

Comment: @barlop The case of נעשה is one of the examples that he mentions.

Answer (score 11):

Hebrew has a **plural of excellence or majesty** for nouns, but not a **royal we** for pronouns. Some people are confused about this because the terms are not kept separated correctly.

Based on what you write, Walter Martin writes about the royal we, which Biblical Hebrew does not have. However, אֱלֹהִים *'ělōhim* (non-Israelite *gods* or the Israelite *God*) is a plural of excellence, which Biblical Hebrew does have.

#### Majestic plural / royal we

Narrowly speaking the *majestic plural* or [*royal we*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we) is the use of a plural pronoun to refer to a singular monarch, as in (for the reference see the Wikipedia page):

> By the Grace of God, We, Alexander I, Emperor and Autocrat of All the Russias ...

As far as I know, when a pronoun is used to refer to God, a singular form is used. (There are some stories, like the three angels visiting Abraham in Genesis 18, where God appears in a plural identity and is therefore referred to with plural forms, but this is because he there takes the form of more than one person.)

The royal we is related to the [T-V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) in languages like French, which can use the second person plural pronoun (*vous*) as a polite / honorific form to address singular persons, instead of the singular form (*tu*). Biblical Hebrew has a different system for polite address; it avoids the second person and uses the third person instead. For example (1 Samuel 26:19):

> וְעַתָּ֗ה יִֽשְׁמַֽע־נָא֙ אֲדֹנִ֣י הַמֶּ֔לֶךְ אֵ֖ת דִּבְרֵ֣י עַבְדֹּ֑ו
> and now, let listen my lord the king to the words of his servant
> And now, my lord the king, please listen to my, your servant's, words.

Joüon & Muraoka (2006: *A Grammar of Biblical Hebrew*. Rome: Gregorian & Biblical Press) state plainly (§114eN):

> The *we* of majesty does not exist in Hebrew.

#### Plural of excellence or majesty

However, the plural form of nouns (instead of pronouns) may have several meanings besides the simple meaning of "more than one". Joüon & Muraoka list a great number of nuances of the plural (§136):

- Plural of extension: שָׁמַ֫יִם *šāmayim* (*sky*, *heavens*), because the heavens are composed of multiple parts
- Plural of composition: דָּמִים *dāmim* (*bloods* > *bloodshed*)
- Plural of intensity: בְּהֵמוֹת *Bəhēmōṯ*, for its greatness
- Plural of abstraction: בַּטֻּחוֹת *baṭṭuḥōṯ* (*security*, from *sure circumstances*)

(The word מַ֫יִם *mayim* (*water*) which you mention can be explained as a plural of extension or composition.)

There is also the plural of excellence or majesty, which occurs in words like:

- אֱלֹהִים *'ělōhim* (non-Israelite *gods* or the Israelite *God*)
- קְדֹשִים *qəḏōšim* (*the Holy One*: Proverbs 9:10; 30:3)
- אֲדֹנִים *'ǎḏōnim* (ordinarily *lords* or *the Lord*, especially in *'ǎḏōnāy* *my Lord*)

It seems that this is, at least in poetry, not restricted to the deity: שֹׁלְחָיו *šōləḥāw* (*he who has sent him*: Proverbs 10:26); מְרִימָיו *mərīmāw* (*he who lifts it*: Isaiah 10:15).

Comment: Thanks..  שֹׁלְחָיו šōləḥāw (he who has sent him: Proverbs 10:26);   Could be those that sent him couldn't it?  every translation I can see translates it as those that sent him.

Comment: @barlop sure that's also possible. The idea behind this translation is probably that people are usually sent by only one person (who is dominant and therefore deserves a plural of excellence). CSB translates it that way, "so the slacker is to the one who sends him on an errand", but you are definitely right that it does not have the majority vote.

Comment: As someone who’s not very familiar with Hebrew, can I just ask why all the vowel/alef-initial words have carets over the following vowel? Is there a difference between _’elōhim_ and _’ělōhim_?

Comment: The German polite / honorific form of address _Sie_ is actually the 3rd p. pl. pronoun “they”. The actual 2nd p. pl. pronoun in German is _ihr_ “you”, it means “du und du, und du, u.s.w.”

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The caret stands for an "ultra-short" (*hatuf*) vowel. These basically stand in for schwa in environments where schwa can't occur, such as after glottals and pharyngeals.

Comment: @YellowSky right, of course, thanks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: In the original manuscripts, there were no vowels... The vowels we have now were added later by scribes who relied on a combination of the oral tradition and common sense and interpretation. One may compare with other manuscripts (e.g. the Samaritan Torah and Qumran Hebrew manuscripts).

Comment: G-d does take plural clitic pronouns on prepositions and verbs a few times, but these are all in sentences that feature an explicit plural of majesty in the name of G-d used, so is likely just strict agreement rather than a royal we. I would also argue that שָׁמַיִם & מַיִם cannot be interpreted as a plural as they both end in máyim not mayīm, with the stress on the wrong syllable. Formally they could be interpreted as _duals_ but this is also problematic comparatively. IMO the best explanation for them is that they are preserved mimated forms reanalysed as preserved duals

Comment: @Tristan yes, they are dual forms, but the dual has the same nuances of extension, composition, etc. The origin of the form is a different matter. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Even "Adonai" has a plural-like end ("my lords" cp. adoni "my lord"), leading to that distinction in the psalm that Jesus reads so much into: Adonai said to adoni, the LORD said to my lord...

Comment: @Keelan Oh yes, didn't read quite to the end of the line... this comment & the last will self-destruct

Comment: Is the "Lord of lords" אֲדֹנֵ֖י הָאֲדֹנִ֑ים in Deuteronomy 10:17 and Psalm 136:3 a "Plural of plural-construct"?

Comment: @Henry,probably an intensifier (That English *best of the best* cannot take a plural is exceptional).

Comment: What about here Lamoh  Is that plural of majesty/honour/emphasis but for a pronoun(lahem) but at teh end of a sentence (lamoh).  Isaiah 44:15

וְהָיָה לְאָדָם, לְבָעֵר, וַיִּקַּח מֵהֶם וַיָּחָם, אַף-יַשִּׂיק וְאָפָה לָחֶם; אַף-יִפְעַל-אֵל וַיִּשְׁתָּחוּ, עָשָׂהוּ פֶסֶל וַיִּסְגָּד-לָמוֹ.

Then a man useth it for fuel; and he taketh thereof, and warmeth himself; yea, he kindleth it, and baketh bread; yea, he maketh a god, and worshippeth it; he maketh it a graven image, and falleth down thereto. (JPS 1917)  (lamoh=them) but graven image / fesel ,  is singular.

Comment: @barlop which word are you referring to? There is *lāḥem* 'bread', not *lāhem* 'to them'. Or do you mean *mēhem* 'from them'? That refers back to the trees from the previous verse which are plural.

Comment: @Keelan I meant to write לָמוֹ is like להם and both are the plural of לו.  Of those three, the verse has לָמוֹ.  So one could ask, why does Isaiah 44:15 use לָמוֹ and not the singular לו .  The word פֶסֶל  (graven image), is singular in form (and translated as singular, so translations take it as singular in meaning).  Yet it is referred to with a plural pronoun לָמוֹ

Comment: @Keelan what about Job 3:14; 6:19; 14:21; 22:17  those all use lamoh and seem to be very much plural.

Comment: @barlop sorry, but I do not have time to discuss all these individual examples. You could consult a reference grammar which would discuss these forms.

Comment: @Keelan No reference grammar I have ever seen says that Lamoh is singular(though it can be hard to find lamoh in a reference grammar). But re the examples I gave, you can just look at one of those examples,  i'll include it here to make it easier.  Job 3:14 "עִם-מְלָכִים, וְיֹעֲצֵי אָרֶץ;    הַבֹּנִים חֳרָבוֹת לָמוֹ"  "With kings and counsellors of the earth, who built up waste places for themselves;"    That's plural.

Comment: @barlop see e.g. Joüon & Muraoka §103f (found through the index of Hebrew words in the back). *lāmō* is an alternative form of *lāhem* and a pausal form of *lō*. My earlier comment was incorrect, apologies.