# What is the evidence that pre-Islamic Arabic had a plural of majesty?

Tags: historical-linguistics, arabic, pronouns, plurality

I'm starting to read the Quran and I've found many theologians argue about God referring to himself in the plural, mainly claiming it is a plural of majesty (example: M. A. S. Abdel Haleem's translation, page xx). Does linguistics agree with this interpretation or is this construction similar to [the answer found here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/38388/does-biblical-hebrew-have-a-plural-of-majesty) where pronouns do not have a plural of majesty? Do we have any examples from pre-Islamic Arabic or evidence from historical linguistics?

Comment: Fyi, linguists are not translators. This is better posted under the religion forum.

Comment: @Lambie whether Pre-Islamic Arabic had a plural of majesty seems like a perfectly acceptable linguistic question. Whether specific examples of plural pronouns in the Qur'an are plurals of majesty would be a religious question

Comment: @Tristan Actually, it is not linguistics. It's about Arabic and translation of Arabic to English. That is not really linguistics per se.

Comment: @Lambie no. The question is not asking about translating particular texts, but the presence or absence of a linguistic feature in a given stage of the language